# When should pivot table models in Laravel be used?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around a problem that I believe requires me to turn a pivot table into a model. Assume there are two tables:

- Group (which has a pivot table group_members, which takes into account different types of users, etc)
- Notifications

Now, the relationship I wanted to model was between Notifications and group_members, as many group_members can be the recipient of a notification, and a many different notifications can be sent out to a particular group_member. This seems to require another pivot table: notification_group_members.

So, really, what it seems to be is that I have a relationship between two pivot tables. I'm not sure if this is a modeling issue, as it seems to be a little odd to create models of pivot tables. The documentation says that *generally* you wouldn't be doing that. Is this one of the cases where it would make sense to?

Comment: I like this kind of questions, so i think (im not an expert) that you dont need one, you can attach a notification to a group using `->attach()` (no need for model) and check for the notifications like this `$notifs = Auth::user()->groups()->notifications();` im not sure if this is right to be honest

Comment: [check this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through "check this")

Comment: This is interesting, I'll give it a shot! The thing about the example is that neither notification nor group_member have any sort of reference to each other, other than via a pivot table, whereas in the documentation example above, two of the three models are directly linked via foreign keys

Comment: the pivot table links them together , eloquent will know how to figure it out, exemple : if you use  `->attach($notif)` to a `group` the `id` of the `notif` and the`id` of the `group` will be added to the pivottable (in one row) , the only thing you need with the pivot table is the correct relation in the groups model and notification model (and at that point im not an expert)

Comment: Pivot table will be created for many-to-many relationship